# How to get the current value of the title attribute in a select?

Tags: select, title

```
<select name="alb_id" id="select_id">
  <option value="0">:: Selecione um álbum ::</option>
  <option title="My first title" value="40">First</option>
  <option title="My second title" value="41">Second</option>
  <option title="My third title" value="59">Third</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Alterar" id="btsend" name="send" class="btedit"/>
```

I'm trying to get the value that is in the title attribute of the select, but I can only get the current select value. Does anyone know how to solve this? Use this code below:

```
$("#btsend").click(function (e) {
    var get_val = $("#select_id").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("title"));
    $("#new_value").val(get_val); //$new_value: I want to here the value of the selected option's title
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
...
var get_val = $('#select_id>option:selected').attr('title');
$("#new_value").text(get_val); //$new_value: I want to here the value of the selected option's title
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked in my case:

```
var data1 = $('#select_id>option:selected').attr('title');
$("input#city").val(data1);
```